# SQL Error [937] [42000]: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I using oracle to calculate with some alias with CTE, but when i run it happen an error

this is my query:

```
WITH BOXCOUNT AS (                                                         
SELECT 
PRODUCT_CODE 

 , ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE)) AS FULLBOX
 
 , CASE WHEN SUM((TOTAL_QUANTITY - ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE))) * PACKING_STYLE) = 0 THEN 0
       WHEN SUM((TOTAL_QUANTITY - ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE))) * PACKING_STYLE) > 0 THEN 1
    END AS SPAREBOX

FROM 
LOG0104M 

GROUP BY 
    PRODUCT_CODE)

SELECT
L04.PRODUCT_CODE
, L04.PRODUCT_NAME 
, L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY
, L04.PACKING_STYLE

, BC.FULLBOX
, BC.SPAREBOX

, SUM(BC.FULLBOX + BC.SPAREBOX) AS TOTALBOX

    
FROM LOG0104M L04
JOIN BOXCOUNT BC
ON   BC.PRODUCT_CODE = L04.PRODUCT_CODE 

GROUP BY  
L04.PRODUCT_CODE
, L04.PRODUCT_NAME
, L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY
, L04.PACKING_STYLE

, BC.FULLBOX
, BC.SPAREBOX
```

this is an error:

```
SQL Error [937] [42000]: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

how i can fix the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change below line of code in CTE

```
CASE WHEN SUM((TOTAL_QUANTITY - ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE))) * PACKING_STYLE) = 0 THEN 0
       WHEN SUM((TOTAL_QUANTITY - ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE))) * PACKING_STYLE) > 0 THEN 1
    END AS SPAREBOX
```

Group by function should be applied on CASE expression i.e.

```
sum(CASE WHEN ((TOTAL_QUANTITY - ROUND((TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE))) * PACKING_STYLE) = 0 THEN 0
       WHEN ((TOTAL_QUANTITY - ROUND((TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE))) * PACKING_STYLE) > 0 THEN 1
    END) AS SPAREBOX
```